# confused in concept of identity provider and outbound authentication in wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2-identity-server

i am newbie to the WSO2 identity server 5.0 service pack one.
I've been so confused lately that, what is different between identity provider and an outbound  authentication?
How can i usage each of them ?
if i define a custom user store authentication, when must be used a custom authentication in Authentication endpoint? what is difference and usage each of them?

Answer (score 0):

Identity providers are providing identity for users to interact with a system. As an example here in wso2 identity server we can configure Facebook as an Identity Provider(IDP). By doing this we can allow users to be logged into Service Providers using facebook credentials. you can follow the blog in [1] to test Wso2 IS with facebook IDP. Otherthan facebook we can use google, Live, Yahoo, etc. as IDP with IS.

[1] http://prasadtissera.blogspot.com/2014/04/login-with-facebook-for-wso2-identity.html

Thanks